# Knockout templating, allBindingsAccessor

Tags: knockout.js

Is there a way to access other binding properties in a template, similar to the allBindingsAccessor of a custom binding?

For instance, pass the slideDuration as in the custom binding example on the Knockout site.

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: buyer, slideDuration:600  }"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a way to directly access "extra" properties that you are passing to the template. When using jQuery Templates it was possible to use the `templateOptions` parameter described [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/quick-tip-reusing-template-by-passing.html).  This is not supported with the native template engine.

The easiest way to accompish what you are after is to pass it as part of the data.  You can even do this anonymously like:

```
data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: { data: buyer, slideDuration:600 }  }"
```

In your template, you would then need to refer to `data` rather than just refer directly to the data's properties.